# Oozie join when one of the forked action is successful

Tags: oozie, fork-join, oozie-workflow

I have a oozie workflow which starts with a fork having two actions watcher1 and watcher2. I need to proceed with join as soon as one of them i.e watcher1 or watcher2  is successful.

Is there something in oozie that i can do to achieve the above mention scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional  statement in join  , after completion of the watcher process  ,generate a dummy file for both the process and check whether this file is already existing or not, if exist then simply send this process to join node directly, if not then schedule the action according to requirement.  Apply this logic for both the watchers. Your join node  should be last node in this process.